Model comparison and experimentation for a thesis result
We are conducting a study to compare the accuracy of two computer vision models:

Model A: Trained on a non-augmented dataset of 11,200 real-world images.
Model B: Trained on an augmented dataset consisting of 800 real-world images, expanded through 13-fold augmentation to 11,200 images.

Both datasets were split into training, validation, and testing sets with 10% of the data used for testing. We aim to determine if there is a significant difference in accuracy between the two models using a T-test.
Here’s where we are stuck:

Should we evaluate the models using their respective test datasets?
Should we combine the test datasets from both models and evaluate on the combined set?
Should we use the test dataset from the non-augmented dataset (real-world images) for evaluation, as it is real-world?

What is the most statistically sound approach?

Are the real world images of model B a subset of those of model A? If not, you can also have a combined data set of only real images that doesn't seem to be covered by your three alternatives. Generally, I'd test on real world data, but I'd also test separately on augmented images just to see how the performance on those is different. And of course for meaningful comparison of the two models you need to evaluate them on the same set of data sets.

Yes, the real world images of model B is a subset of those of model A. So, based on your response, the third option is the best fit, right? If so, will that create a bias for model A since we will be using its test dataset to evaluate Model B?

However, I’m also thinking that it won’t create bias for Model A since Model B is based on a subset of Model A. Does this make sense?

You want to evaluate on a test set that is relevant for your actual application. Chances are that this is about real world images, so you want to know how well your model works on real world images, so third option. Of course chances are Model A is better and Model B may work better for its own test set, but the important thing is that test set A should be used if this is what is relevant in your situation.
